# When using GCP Cloud Build to deploy to App Engine the file upload to Google Cloud Storage step is very slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Deploying a Google App Engine App using Google Cloud Build is considerably slower (a magnitude of order slower) compared with deploying an app locally using gcloud app deploy from the dev machine.
According to the build log, the much slower step is the one involving application file upload to Google Cloud Storage. One could expect that given the process is actually running on Google cloud, this step would be faster compared with a local deployment.
For example uploading ~1000 application files locally will typically take a minute or so, but on Cloud Build it may take 10 to 20 minutes.
Here's the Cloud Build config:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >-
        gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 2100 && gcloud app deploy
        app_yaml_file_here.yaml --version version_name_here --promote
    entrypoint: bash
timeout: 2100s
```

The build is pooling the app files from an online repository (quick). The delay occurs upon upload to GCS:

```
Beginning deployment of service [service_name]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 1005 files to Google Cloud Storage             ═╣
╚════════════════════════
```

The above step took some 15 minutes to complete.
Any ideas why this is happening are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have 1000+ files?

Comment: Yes, around ~1500 actually.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I get the tip to use `.gcloudignore`, but it is not working every time for us. Mostly here to let you know that you are not alone 

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing Google Cloud Build to deploy an App Engine, there could be a number of reasons why the file upload phase to Google Cloud Storage is sluggish. Large file sizes, constrained bandwidth, throttling, the Cloud Build instance type, and the GCS bucket setup are a few examples of potential causes. It is advised to examine the Cloud Build logs and use instruments like Cloud Monitoring to find the source of the sluggish upload in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is this a GPT generated answer?